# Vue router inherit parent properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js

I'm fairly new to `vue.js` and I'm currently trying to setup my different routes. I'm using sub routes, since the "logged in" user will have a different UI than a visitor.

Currently my setup is like this:

```
routes: [
    {
        path: '/auth',
        name: 'auth',
        component: test,
        meta: {
            auth: false
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'login',
                name: 'login',
                component: login
            },
            {
                path: 'signup',
                name: 'signup',
                component: signup
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        path: '/user',
        name: 'user',
        component: test,
        meta: {
            auth: true
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'profile',
                name: 'profile',
                component: login
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

While this is working, I'm wondering why child routes don't take over the parents `meta` properties. Do I need to assign the `meta.auth` to each sub route? Or is there any way to inherit this?

Essentially in the `router.beforeEach`, I want to check if the user is authenticated correctly or not. But only on child routes of `/user`

I'm also coming from an `angular` background, so I'm used to nesting routes, not sure if this is the best way in Vue.

Comment: Nested routes sure is the right way to divide the page into reasonable parts. For the inheritence, I feel those code above is most probably treated as plain objects, since they're `config`s, and most frameworks have us declare classes/components separately when they want to do inheritence and other pre-process for us.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 In `angular` for example, if you declare a child route, it will inherit the properties from the parent. So I was just wondering how this works in `vue`. It's not a big deal to declare those properties on each child route, but it would've been easier if i only had to declare them on the parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/704

I didn't realise this was deprecated in Vue-router 2.0, it is possible to get the matched route and find the meta there.

Answer (score 2):

With vue-router v.3 to match **parent**'s meta (for example: in `beforeEach()` func. ) You need to use `to.matched.some()` like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)) {
    
      // ...
      next({name:'route-name'})
    
  } else {

      next()
  }

}
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html